# Trouble with defining rules in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
married(man, woman).
married(B, A) :- 
  married(A, B)
```

If `B` is married to `A`, `A` is married to `B`.
I understand that writing it as I have creates a loop, but I don't know how to prevent this.

```
parent(Parent, Child) :- 
    parent(married(Parent, Spouse), Child).
```

I am also unable to do something like this.

If `Parent` is the parent of `Child` :-
        the spouse of `Parent` is the parent of `Child`.

Comment: In olden times, you could reserve one position for the man and the other for the woman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two separate predicates. First you define a predicate that lists facts:

```
married_fact(philip, elisabeth).
married_fact(william, kate).

married(X, Y) :-
    married_fact(X, Y).
married(X, Y) :-
    married_fact(Y, X).
```

> I am also unable to do something like this:
>
> If `Parent` is the parent of `Child` :-
> the spouse of `Parent` is the parent of `Child`.

The syntax `parent(married(Parent, Spouse), Child).` does not make much sense, since `married(Parent, Spouse)` is here a functor. Even if Prolog would see it as a predicate, a predicate does not "return" anything. A predicate is either true or false.

You can define a `parent_fact/2` predicate:

```
parent_fact(phillip, charles).
```

and then define a predicate:

```
parent(Parent, Child) :-
    parent_fact(Parent, Child).
parent(Parent, Child) :-
    married(Parent, Spouse),
    parent_fact(Spouse, Child).
```